# how to display sub-sub categories on left side

Tags: magento-1.7, category-tree

please visit [**my site link**](http://joinery.newtrendzonline.com/)

In `POWER TOOLS` category, go for `FESTOOL` Sub-category. You can see `DRILLING AND FASTENING` sub-sub Category there. But those`DRILLING AND FASTENING` sub-sub
category is not visible properly as it is present after monitor width.

What I need to do is, when we hover mouse on `FESTOOL`, I want to display `DRILLING AND FASTENING` sub-sub Category and other sub-sub categories on left side. If Possible, I want to do these changes only for `POWER TOOLS` category in my site, so that every category menu link is visible directly in my site.

Please help me to find solution.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is totally css works...

Comment: This could be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512032/detect-if-dropdown-navigation-would-go-off-screen-and-reposition-it

Comment: thanks @SamuelComan in what file i have to edit , is it in theme.css , can we use inspect element to find solution.

Comment: I'll leave my answer below.

Comment: @SamuelComan , can you help me , in what file, what code i have to edit? please help me for that.... thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url I mentioned (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512032/detect-if-dropdown-navigation-would-go-off-screen-and-reposition-it) uses a JS + CSS solution. This means, beside editing a css file, you would have to create a js file or add that js to a phtml file in your template.

If you don't need a general solution, a quick CSS solution which will work only for that specific menu is:

```
   .header-nav-container-home ul.nav-menu li.nav-5-1 ul li.parent:hover ul {
       left: -100%;
   }
```

Add this line at the end of menu.css.

**EDIT**

CSS selectors explanation:

`.header-nav-container-home ul.nav-menu` - main menu

`.header-nav-container-home ul.nav-menu li.nav-5-1` - first child of the fifth menu item (in your case Festool)

`.header-nav-container-home ul.nav-menu li.nav-5-1 ul li.parent:hover ul` - every sub- submenu of Festool

So, I told the browser to reposition only the sub, sub-menus of Festool. Want every sub- sub-menu of Power Tools, change "nav-5-1" to "nav-5". The rule then becomes:

```
  .header-nav-container-home ul.nav-menu li.nav-5 ul li.parent:hover ul {
   left: -100%;
  }
```

And so on...

Comment: hi, you are a genius, thanks a lot, it's worked....

Comment: hi, one liitle change i needed. if you go for "Power tools => "festool" its not working. but it's working for "Power tools => festool => jigsaws" . please help me to find solution.

Comment: I'll edit my response and add some explanations.

Comment: ya, sure..... okay....

Comment: ya, there is lot to learn from you,  really your comments gave me some knowledge about menus. thanks a lot.